# How to install msodbcsql in microsoft AZURE server (PaaS)

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, database-connection, paas

Okay, so basically I have now deployed an Web App in Azure, but I cannot seem to make it to connect to a separate SQL SERVER. I have provided all the desired App settings for the connection but it seems no good.

Now I search for possible causes:

1. PHP `ext` dlls are missing for msodbcsql which are

> php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
>   and
>   php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

I already added this dll's and referenced them accordingly base on this document [Configure via ini settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-php-configure)

2. Now the uncertainty that msodbcsql is installed in Azure.

Now this is what I am having problem with.

So in my case in number 2 I tried copying the installer to Azure *D:/home/*

and run this in the command line

`msiexec /quiet /passive /qn /i msodbcsql.msi IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES ADDLOCAL=ALL`

which is suppose to install the .msi installer but i always get an

> ACCESS IS DENIED

error.

is there another way around??

Answer (score 2):

Basically Azure has already set up extension `php_sqlsrv.dll` & `php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll` for us, so we ourselves do not need to install any driver to connect SQL SERVER.

You could check the `php.ini` file which can be found at `D:\local\Config\PHP-<version>\php.ini` with Kudu console to confirm that.

[image]

Also, you can check that with `phpinfo()` function in your application.

[image]
[image]

And I have tested it with the following lines of code and got it worked.

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. it turns out that you are correct,
my problem i was having was i need to add my IP in AWS server to allow connection to the DB.
now I can connect to the SQL server.
thanks for the tip.